# Bootstrap navbar doesn't showed up

Tags: navbar

I'm currently learning how to create a theme for my drupal website, using Bootstrap.

I follow step by step a tutorial, but I can't figure why the navbar doesn't show up properly. Is it related to JQuery ?

Could you help me ? Is my code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Pauvre mais ravi theme</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>

     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
       <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
         <li class="nav-item active">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item dropdown">
           <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
           <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
           </div>
         </li>
       </ul>
       <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
         <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
         <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
       </form>
     </div>
   </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [bootstrap's navbar documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/), you should add class `navbar-expand-lg` to get hamburger button and `bg-light` to get light gray background color. Your `<nav>` tag should be like this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: Thank you ! It's better but it still doesn't show the way it should :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to include CSS in head tag(before ending ) in you HTML.

Try this code! I dont have your app.css with me. so try to include it in the

Good luck!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>

     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
       <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
         <li class="nav-item active">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item dropdown">
           <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
           <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
           </div>
         </li>
       </ul>
       <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
         <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
         <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
       </form>
     </div>
   </nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Basic Navbar Example</h3>
  <p>A navigation bar is a navigation header that is placed at the top of the page.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```